# TypeError: res.render is not a function, while trying to use view engine in server-side using express and ejs

Tags: express, ejs

I was going through a tutorial about templates. I was just following "code along" rule to learn using templates. I am getting error saying res.render is not a function. But same thing done in  tutor is able generate result.

This is my code using Express (Node):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(res, req) {

  var today = new Date();
  var currentDay = today.getDay();
  var day = "";

    switch (currentDay) {
      case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
      case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;

      case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;

      case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;

      case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;

      case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;

      case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;

      default:
      console.log("Error: Current day is " + currentDay);

    }

   res.render("list.ejs", {
      kindOfDay:day
  });

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running in port:3000");
});
```

in express docs for using templates, it's shown to use extension also in res.render(). Also tried it. Still it's showing 'error:res.render is not a function'.
 - kindOfDay is ejs element that i have used in list.ejs file in views directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for app.get() method you wrote
`app.get('/', function(res, req) {  code ...` 
and also `res.render("list.ejs", {kindOfDay:day });`
though we can provide any arguments of our choice as you have written `(res,req)` as arguments in the callback function, actually you have to write `req.render(...)`  as well. or you can change the arguments for the sake of convention as `(request, response)` or `(req, res)` and then it will be okay.

Maybe it was just a typo..
For more information check express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

As we know, parameters hold the place for upcoming arguments. So, if in the function the first parameter is specified to take req from the client side, then you can not be able to send the response via that same parameter. For example,

function intro(name,age){
return  `I am ${name}, and my age is ${age}`
}

If we call the above function passing name and age as 'babal' and 23, respectively, then the return value would be `I am babal, and my age is 23`. whereas, if we pass the values like intro(23, 'babal'), then the return value is like `I am 23, and my age is 'babal'`.

so in the end, the placement of the arguments matters while calling the function.